# How to assign a NSMutableSet data into an NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created a `NSMutableSet` and add some objects from another `NSMutableSet`. Then I passed this objects to an `NSArray` but the objects are not assigned.

Here is my code:

```
NSMutableSet *tagsSetArray = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:issueTags];
NSArray *tagArray =[tagsSetArray allObjects];
```

Comment: Why do you need the first line? Are you sure issueTags containts objects?

Comment: try this NSMutableArray *array = [[yourset allObjects] mutableCopy];

Answer (score 1):

Use following way to cast NSMutableSet into NSArray :

```
NSArray *array = [YourSet allObjects];
```

For more information : http://www.springtiger.co.uk/2010/09/06/create-a-nsarray-from-a-nsset/

Comment: Note that you have misapplied the term "cast".

Answer (score 0):

try to using NSMutableArray

```
NSMutableSet*issueTags=[NSMutableSet setWithObjects:@"hai",@"hello",nil];
NSMutableSet*tagsSetArray=[NSMutableSet setWithSet:issueTags];
NSMutableArray*tagArray=[[tagsSetArray allObjects] mutableCopy];
NSLog(@"%@",tagArray);//hai,hello
```

Comment: There is no need for the `mutableCopy` call, if one does not want a mutable array.